Wrong scp destination path
I'm copying a website from remote server to another and I have
SOURCE SERVER 
/var/www/vhosts/namesiteA.com
    /FolderA
    /FolderB

DESTINATION SERVER
/var/www/vhosts/namesiteB.com

  

After running the following bash:
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="root@111.222.333.444:/var/www/vhosts/namesiteA.com/"
DESTINATION="/var/www/vhosts/namesiteB.com/"
sshpass -p "<source_server_pass>" scp -p -r "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"

works fine, but I expect:
DESTINATION SERVER
/var/www/vhosts/namesiteB.com
    /FolderA
    /FolderB 

instead I get:
/var/www/vhosts/namesiteB.com
    /namesiteA.com
        /FolderA
        /FolderB


With the new SFTP-based protocol for scp you need a trailing . on the source directory path:
SOURCE="root@111.222.333.444:/var/www/vhosts/namesiteA.com/."

Unfortunately if you're using a legacy version of scp that uses the old scp protocol, and it's new enough to be updated with a fix for CVE-2018-20685, the trailing dot will break the copy. See scp: error: unexpected filename
